# How to make covariant Consumer<? extends Base> work?

Tags: java, covariance, variance

This is the smallest code sample I could come up with to illustrate the problem:

```
public void consumeDerived(Consumer<Derived> derivedConsumer, Derived derivedParameter) {
    consumeBase(derivedConsumer, derivedParameter);
}

public void consumeBase(Consumer<? extends Base> baseConsumer, Base baseParameter) {
    baseConsumer.accept(baseParameter);
}
```

The idea is that the call to `consumeDerived` simply gets passed along to the `consumeBase` method. To my understanding, the call `baseConsumer.accept()` should be able to take type `Base` or type `Derived extends Base`.

However I get the error: `java: incompatible types: Base cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? Base`.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Consumer<? extends Base>` is a consumer of *something* which extends a `Base`. It may be a `Consumer<Derived>`, and that wouldn't be able to accept a `Base` as an argument - it's not specific enough.

You can add a generic type parameter to solve this:

```
public <T extends Base> void consumeBase(Consumer<T> baseConsumer, T baseParameter) {
    baseConsumer.accept(baseParameter);
}
```

It's also worth noting that `consumeDerived` is now superfluous.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I don't understand what the difference in meaning is between your code and mine.

Comment: @Hatch a `Consumer<Integer>` can't consume a `Number`, but a `Consumer<Integer>` is a `Consumer<? extends Number>`.

Comment: @Hatch When you use a wildcard (`?`) you're basically saying "the type can be anything that matches and I don't care what it actually is". In your case, that's not true. You must care about the actual type. When you use a generic type parameter, all occurrences must resolve to the same type (`T` must be either a `Base` in both cases or a `Derived` in both cases).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Hatch Happy to help. It'd be a good idea for you to go over the [Oracle generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). It's not very long and it should contain all the info you need.